# Оптимизация изображений для сайта - php Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

Нужно оптимизировать изображения так чтобы проходить проверку Gtmetrix или Google PageSpeed Insights (результат у них одинаковый), для этого использую php расширение ImageMagick и его класс Imagick. На данный момент оптимизирую таким образом:

```
$im = new Imagick('image1.png');
$im->setImageInterlaceScheme(Imagick::INTERLACE_PNG);
$im->optimizeImageLayers();
$im->stripImage();
```

Эти методы довольно хорошо сокращает объем неоптизированных png-шников, но все равно недостаточно для того чтобы проходить проверку. В этом вопросе хочу узнать, кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой и как еще можно оптимизировать изображения, как это делают в Google?

Comment: при загрузке картинки делается несколько экземпляров разных размеров, preview, средняя, и полная к примеру, и там где надо выводиться, вот и все

Comment: Нет, нужно именно оптимизировать изображение, удалить к примеру метаданные, всячески сжать её, в гугл это делают без потери качества.